# Rspec + Capybara webkit: Not directed to path stated in test, instead root path syntax detected

Tags: rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am running a rspec test of visiting a path and creating a new conversation on that page. However, i can't understand why i am getting the error below even though i have clearly stated `visit conversations_path`. The link_to statement written in the error message is found on my root path.

When i remove the link_to code from my root path, the test passes.

**conversation_spec.rb**

```
describe "Conversation" do

    let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let!(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:friend) }

    before do
        login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    end

    describe 'index' do

        before do
          visit conversations_path
        end

        it 'can be reached successfully' do
            expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)
        end

        it "create a new conversation", **js: true** do
            visit conversations_path
            expect(current_path).to eq(conversations_path)
            click_on "Compose"
            expect(page).to have_css('.new_message_head')

        end

    end
```

**Failure:**

```
 1) Conversation index create a new conversation
     Failure/Error: <h4><%= link_to featured_article.title, article_path(featured_article) %></h4>

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific error shown is because `featured_article` is nil, most likely because you haven't created any articles for your test.  As for why it's going to the root path rather than conversations, that's impossible to say for sure without seeing the conversations controller and/or the relevant part of the `test.log`.  However, I do have 2 guesses as to what's happening.

1. The conversations path requires articles to exist so it knows what to show, and you aren't creating any in the test data so it's redirecting to root
2. You're calling visit twice in a row without verifying it completed.  With your before blocks your test boils down to

   login_as(user, :scope => :user)
   visit conversations_path
   visit conversations_path
   ...

Since `visit` is not guaranteed to wait for its action to complete before returning (drivers try their best but it is not always possible), it is possible the second visit request is occurring before the first one returns.  Assuming the `login_as` you're using is the devise/warden test mode version it works by setting up middleware to setup the user as logged in on the next request (and only the next request) received.  This then sets the session cookie which gets returned with the response keeping the user logged in beyond that request.  If the second `visit` occurs before the response from the first `visit` is received and processed the session cookie won't be set in the second request and therefore the user won't actually be logged in - hence causing a redirect to the root path.

The `test.log` should identify exactly which cause it is (or just try removing the extra `visit`)

On a separate note:  It is generally a bad smell to be testing response codes in feature tests which should instead be focused on what the user can see on the page.  Also, you should never use the `eq` matcher with `current_path` since it can lead to flaky tests when using JS capable drivers and dynamic pages.  Instead you should use the Capybara provided `have_current_path` matcher - `expect(page).to have_current_path(conversations_path)`